# Making a centered text class in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-helper, center

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up some CSS stuff.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>My Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mysite.com/general.css" />
</head>
<body>
<text class="center" Welcome!>
</br>
<img src="<myimage>" alt="Logo" class="center">
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my general.css file:

```
img.center {display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
body{background-color:#b0c4de;}
text{font-family:"Lucida Console";}
text.center{font-family:"Lucida Console"; text-align:center;}
```

My image is centered, like I want it to be.
However, I would like to setup my text to always use Lucida Console as the font. But I also want to be able to setup a specific class for centering the font, like there is for the image.

Could anyone please help me do this? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `text` element looks invalid. You don't have to put a text element around text, and at least not in this way.

Try this:

```
p {
  font-family: 'Lucida Console'; 
}
p.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then your paragraphs will look like this:

```
<p>Your text goes here</p>
<p class="center">Your centered text goes here</p>
<p>Your text goes here</p>
```

By the way, it is unwise to call such a class 'center', because it only says how it looks, not what it means. Instead, try to determine what kind of information is in this centered paragraph (like a 'message', or 'welcome message') and name your class accordingly. That way, the document contains the actual document structure and meta descriptions in the form of classes, while the actual layout is fully specified in CSS.
Then, when you want your messages to be italic instead of centered, you can just alter the class in the css file and you're done.

Comment: I've been hard-pressed to find a semantic "excuse" for centering things wihout bloated CSS (declaring it on lots of separate elements). I wouldn't say it's "unwise", because anyone working on the HTML or CSS will understand it's presentational meaning immediately, I would say it's maybe "impure" in regards to content/presentation separation. But yeah, it's about as bad as a `<center>` tag... But how does one name classes semantically for aligning images to the left or right without `.left` and `.right`?

Comment: Thank you GolezTrol. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @WesleyMurch The question is wrong. :) You shouldn't ask "How to name the class for aligning images to the left". But "How to name the class for aligning thumbnails in the 'recent event' overview" or something. Then, you can make up a good class and decide that this kind of image should align left or right (or in turn). Of course, when aligning images 'randomly' in a big article, there are no real rules and you will have to see what looks good per picture. In that case, I can imagine you want to use 'left' and 'right' classes.

Comment: I understand what you mean completely. It's something that I think is a necessary evil sometimes. All our sites are 90% client-generated WYSIWYG content so semantic classes are very difficult to accomplish within pages/posts, we have to use `left` and `right`, and generic psuedo-semantic classes like `content-box`.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you're using  but take a look at this example: -

http://jsfiddle.net/JPzRr/1/

```
img.center {display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
body{background-color:#b0c4de;}
p {font-family:"Lucida Console";}
p.center {
    font-family:"Lucida Console";
    text-align:center;
}

<body>
    <p class="center">Welcome!</p>
<br />
<img src="<myimage>" alt="Logo" class="center">
```

Comment: `<p class="center"> Welcome!</text>` and `</br>` are both incorrect, and your fiddle is quite a mess as well.

Comment: It's just not worth it for anyone to rush out broken answers with bad examples, OP seems misinformed as it is. Take the day off before this stuff sneaks into your real code :)